# How can I make mouse-overs provide more description?

Tags: starcraft-2

In WoL, mousing over an ability, armor, or damage showed all of the statistics for it. HotS seems to have disabled this by default and I've toggled what seem to be the relevant "Gameplay" commands in single player but haven't been able to solve the issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe it's the "Display Game tooltips" options under the "Gameplay" menu

[image]